# Android 9.0 use intent open image always show black result

Tags: java, android

I hope use intent open image in android 9.0

[here](https://github.com/chikadance/android-intent-open-img) is my full code

I use following code:

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/green.jpg");
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)/**/
                .setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file), "image/*")
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and I'm sure image exist and `<provider>` exist in AndroidManifest.xml
the logcat show following without any error

```
START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://ro.opendir.provider/external_storage_root/Download/green.jpg typ=image/* flg=0x1 cmp=com.android.gallery3d/.app.GalleryActivity} from uid 10074
```

but result black empty:

[image]

when i use builtin "Files" app to open same image:

and the logcat show:

```
06-09 11:48:02.708 480-1594/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/green.jpg typ=image/jpeg flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.gallery3d/.app.GalleryActivity} from uid 10022
```

the result is

[image]

Comment: Replace `<external-path
            name="files_root"
            path="Android/data/${applicationId}"/>` with `<external-files-path
            name="files_root"
            path="."/>` and see if that helps (as what you have is not going to work and might be interfering with `FileProvider`). Note that you will not have read/write access to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in Android Q/R, so you might want to start moving your content elsewhere anyway.

Comment: It doesn't work since in my code, I have `    <external-path name="external_storage_root" path="."/>` and I try to remove "file_root", it still get black empty result

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason and solution,

in short, my app has not "Storage" permission, when i manually enable it in app info(see following img), I can open image in intent and image show correctly
[image]

detail:

even i add use-permission for storage, but in my code, I open image with intent in MainActivity #onCreate, so I have no change to allow "access storage" permission dialog, I may change my code to first make sure my app has "storage" permission